# ColdFusion, MySQL, single quotes

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, single-quotes

I am using ColdFusion 11 and a MySQL5 database, with everything set to UTF-8 character encoding. I am having trouble making my selects work properly when they contain single quotes. Here is a simple example:

I have a simple piece of sql:

```
select * from table where column = 'I've got a single quote';
```

In my sql client I need to modify this to escape the single quote, thus:

```
select * from table where column = 'I''ve got a single quote';
```

And this works correctly.

And in ColdFusion, the query looks like this:

```
    <cfquery name="qryName" datasource="dsn">
            select * from table where column = <cfqueryparam CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="I've got a single quote" />
    </cfquery>
```

However, the row is not returned and there is no error.

I tried using preserveSingleQuotes too, but still nothing is returned:

```
<cfqueryparam CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#preserveSingleQuotes(I've got a single quote)#" />
```

Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

--- NON-ISSUE ---

Seems my test wasn't good enough. The data I was testing with turned out not to be as I expected. I was getting data from a JSON packet which, when dumped to a browser showed this string:

```
Didn't vote
```

However, when I examined the actual packet I saw that the JSON representation of the string was this:

```
Didn&#39;t vote
```

And therefore didn't match what was in the database. So, my bad, this is not an issue, and all faith in the power of cfqueryparam is restored :-)

Comment: I do not see anything obvious. cfqueryparam (alone) should work fine. Is that the actual code used, hard coded value and all?

Comment: @Leigh No, that's not the actual code, just a simplified representation of it. The point I am trying to raise is that I expect <cfqueryparam> to escape the single quote for me, and therefore match what's in the database, but it isn't doing it. I've never had this problem using Oracle so I'm guessing it's something to do with the ColdFusion-MySQL communication. Maybe?

Comment: Did you verify the problem with something very simple, such as the what you have in your question?

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk Yes, indeed I did. This is just an even more simplified version for illustration of the issue.

Comment: @Junglefish - I understand, but I have used it many times and it does work, so .. *something* must be different than we are aware of (test code you are using, input, database values, environment, etcetera). Guess what I am asking is did you reproduce it with a cfquery that is exactly as basic as the code above - hard coded values and all? Ignoring the fake table and column name of course.

Comment: @Leigh My actual test was slightly more complex, involving passing a few variables around. All the code is in a different environment to where I am right now so I'll post a newer version of the actual test for you to look at some time later tonight.

Comment: I wonder if that quote in DB is actually a quote. Can you do a hex dump of it and verify that it is not something special.

Comment: Okay, this is a NON-ISSUE. Please see my additional comments. And thanks all for trying to help.

Comment: Rule # 1 - Browsers lie ;-)